# AzureでのMFA利用時の制限について

Tags: azure

Office365を会社で利用しており、AzureにてMFAの設定を有効にしようと思っています。
会社内で接続するときはMFAを無効（スキップ）にして、自宅で接続する時にはMFAを有効にしたいと考えております。
資料をみると実現できるようなのですが、フェデレーション環境がないと設定ができないようなのですが、フェデレーション環境がないクラウドのみの利用で、実現可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

条件によってMFAを有効化したりスキップするようなカスタマイズはADFSのMFAを使わないと実現できなかったかと思います。
（Office 365で提供されるMFAはそこまでカスタマイズできないかと思われます）

Comment: 今ならAzure ADの条件付きアクセス機能で対応できそうですね。(P1ライセンスが必要ですが）

- [条件付きアクセスとは](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/overview)